# What's the problem with this honda

Tags: honda, starting, ignition, odyssey

I own 2003 Honda Odyssey 3.5L. not sure if it's ex or Lx.  First key wouldn't unlock doors then it wouldn't turn in ignition n now car won't start at all.  Battery is good I'm Don't know if starts bad or not. Do I need an ignition switch or the lock assembly or both?  Can I program the keys myself or got to pay locksmith to do that? I should add my keys are obviously worn out bad n valet key pattern is way different the primary key.
Help

Comment: Do you have 2 keys?  Does the other one work?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!